# Retrieving Images from SQL Server in Android

Tags: android, sql-server, image, listview

When I add the images to res>drawable and display it using an array to display them in listview it works fine. But how can retrieve the images from SQL Server database.

This is my MainCourse.java which is the main.java like to display the images.

```
package com.example.lenovo.redcabins;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Lenovo on 4/27/2017.
 */

public class MainCourseList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] itemname;
    private final Integer[] imgid;

    public MainCourseList(Activity context, String[] itemname, Integer[] imgid) {
        super(context, R.layout.maincourse, itemname);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.context=context;
        this.itemname=itemname;
        this.imgid=imgid;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.maincourse, null,true);

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_maincourselist1);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img_maincourse);
        TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_maincourserlist2);

        txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
        extratxt.setText("Description "+itemname[position]);
        return rowView;

    };

}
```

This is my Main Course List java which contains array adapter to display images

How can I display the images from SQL Server?

I know that I have to create a connection class and i know the way to do it. And the image type I have used to store my data is 'image'. How can I change it to array form. I'm a beginner

Comment: data type to store image in sql server is 'image'

Comment: Store Their Id In Your Sql Database or  Uri then retrieve them and load them.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `**Model Class**`

```
class ImageData{

private String title;
private String Des;
private Uri uriImage; //store uri here
private String Base64; store image in form of string .!

}




public class BitmapConvertorUtility {

public static String encodeToBase64(Bitmap image, Bitmap.CompressFormat compressFormat, int quality)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    image.compress(compressFormat, quality, byteArrayOS);
    return Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOS.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
}

public static Bitmap decodeBase64(String input)
{
    byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(input, 0);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedBytes, 0, decodedBytes.length);
}




}

Bitmap image= BitmapConvertorUtility.decodeBase64(imageStr);
```

now You Just need only one Object list To populate your all data.!

load your all data in Object then at it to list  and pass it to adapter.!

You can Store Images By decoding to Base64, or Store Uri of Your Images in Sql Server and load them using their uri and pass them to Glide or Picasso  to load.!

Comment: now i have changed it to varbinary(max) can you give code examples to how get the images using result set

Comment: @JoeKevinRayan edited My answer maybe it helps you. now.!

Answer (score 0):

As i have knowledg, there is no way to get all images in array from sql server to android. 
For more information [Follow this link](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-programming-tutorial-to-get-all-images-from-server/)